# For every invertible matrix $S$ there exist bases $B$, $B'$ such that $S = M_{B'}^{B}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to prove:
$V$ vector space, $\dim V < \infty$. 
For every invertible matrix $S=[s_{ij}]$ there exist bases $B$, $B'$ such that $S = M_{B'}^{B}$

So, let $B' = \{b_1', \dots ,b_n'\}$ be a basis of $V$. Let $B:=\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$, $b_1,\dots,b_n \in V$ such that $b_j = s_{1j}\cdot b_j'$. We need to prove that $B$ is a basis of V.

(1) generator set: Since $B'$ is Basis, $\forall v \in V: v= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ib_i' = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i \cdot \frac{1}{s_{1i}}b_i$, $\Rightarrow$ $B$ is a generator set.

This is where I'm struggling. $S$ is invertible, but of course it could be that $s_{ij} = 0$ for some $i,j$. How to go on?

Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand your usage of $M$.. what would $M$ be?

Comment: It's  the change of bases Matrix, so M changes from B to B'